# Selenium WebDriver with C#: How to locate and click a checkbox with certain class and title attributes?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project using Selenium and C#. I need to click a checkbox on a web page with the following attributes: class 'QvOptional_LED_CHECK_363636' and title 'Atom_Handler'.

However, I have not been able to successfully click the checkbox(Atom_Handler). Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

I saved the website as for your reference.
[Git Repository](https://github.com/JDiaz027/Power-Portal)

I've tried using the FindElement method to locate the checkbox element by its class name, as well as the FindElements method to find all elements with the specified class name and iterating through them to find the checkbox element, but I haven't been able to successfully click the checkbox.

No exception or error messages are being sent to me. After a brief period of time, the Microsoft Edge browser closes and the system remains inactive. The system's output is shown here. [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/3DW0mcB6)

```
try
{
    using (IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(qlikViewUrl);

        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("QvOptional_LED_CHECK_363636"));

        foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("title") == "Atom_Handler")
            {
                element.Click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(WebDriverException x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, x.Message, "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I'm hoping to get some suggestions or solutions from the community on how to properly locate and click the checkbox element(Atom_Handler and the rest of the checkboxex) using Selenium and C#. Specifically, I'd like to know how to identify the correct element using its class and title attributes, and how to interact with the checkbox element to simulate a click event. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide a link to the page. While the full HTML of the page is somewhat useful, it's not nearly as useful as seeing the actual page fully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the `unselecable="on"` property on the `<div>` you are trying to click, before the click.
Or rather try to click using JS:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that your locator is locating 42 elements on the provided HTML. That's not very specific and it might be getting the wrong one. Make your locator more specific by using the CSS selector

```
div.QvOptional_LED_CHECK_363636[title='Atom_Handler']
```

That returns exactly and only the element you are looking for.